# PowerShell save file as xls but output was html

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a file which file extension is .xls, but the weird thing is when save as, the default is go to html file.

[image]

[image]

This caused a problem when I'm using my powershell script to perform some action on the file and saved it as xls file. The result is the script generate one xls file and one folder which contain html file. Is there a way to fix this issues ? I just want to save the file as xls file wihout any html files. Any helps are much appreciated.

[image: The]

[image]

Here the code that I use to save file as .xls

```
Function RenameTab ($ExcelFileName, $OutLoc)
{
$excelFile = "D:\Projects\" + $excelFileName + ".xls"
$xldoc =  New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$xldoc.Visible = $false
$xldoc.DisplayAlerts = $false

$workbook = $xldoc.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Worksheets)
{
    $n = $ExcelFileName ##+ "_" + $worksheet.Name
    $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
    $worksheet.name = "Sheet1"
    $workbook.SaveAs($OutLoc + $n + ".xlsx")
    $workbook.Close()
}
$xldoc.Quit()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `SaveAs`, you should really specify the [file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx).

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) for `SaveAs`, it would be the second argument, so the corrected line would be:

```
$workbook.SaveAs($OutLoc + $n + ".xlsx", 51) # 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

I don't have all that much experience with COM interaction, but you might be able to use the enumeration directly somehow and make the line similar to:

```
$workbook.SaveAs($OutLoc + $n + ".xlsx", $xldoc.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
```